# L2 ACL to filter L3/L4 traffic

Tags: hp, hp-comware

Would it be possible to restrict access to a device using L2 ACL on HP Comware switch which is L2 for the given VLAN?

I want to secure the access to a device on specific VLAN so it can be accessed only from specific MACs/IPs.

Can the L2 ports filter traffic based on L3 and L4 information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a routed packet carries the router's MAC address as source in its frame: no, that's not possible. Layer 2 doesn't have enough information to filter L3 traffic.

However, if everything happens within the same L2 segment/VLAN you can filter out the source MACs you don't want. You'd have to include all (non-filtering) routers as they could be used to circumvent the filtering.

That being said and from your comment: many layer 2 (=non-routing) switches can also filter by layer 3 and 4 information - it depends on the specific hardware.

Comment: I'm confused. Answers on some forums like this one https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/wan-routing-and-switching/access-list-on-l2-swicth/td-p/1355804 states that it is possible to use standard ACLs on L2 interface. So maybe it is depending on the hardware?

Comment: The scope of ACLs depends on the specific hardware, of course. You were asking asking about _L2 ACLs_ being able to filter _by L3/L4 information_ - which isn't possible, It's quite possible that an L2 switch features L3/L4 ACLs, however.

Comment: Just to clarify, some L3 switches can apply L3 ACLs to L2 traffic (port based ACL) such as described https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3850/software/release/3se/security/configuration_guide/b_sec_3se_3850_cg/b_sec_3se_3850_cg_chapter_01010.html#ID90